# manually perform SignedXml.CheckSignature in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, xml, compact-framework, signedxml

I was looking for some implementation of SignedXml.CheckSignature for .net CF with no success. How to perform this function manually? I have XML file signed with function SignedXml.ComputeSignature on desktop machine with full .net framework. And I need to check signature for this XML file in .net CF. I tried to use RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData to check whole SignedInfo node against SignatureValue, but it does not work. Is there needed some canonicalization for SignedInfo?

Comment: The `<SignedInfo>` element should contain a `<CanonicalizationMethod>` indicating how to canonicalize the data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedinfo.canonicalizationmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried this canonicalization but with no effect. VerifyData still returns false